# Can multiple Kafka consumers read from the same partition of same topic by default?

Tags: apache-kafka

Can multiple Kafka consumers read from the same partition of same topic by default? By default, I mean since group.id is not mandatory I am wondering if I spawn multiple kafka consumers without specifying any group.id and give them the same topic and partition name will they be able to read from the same partition? I understand that If I give different group names for each Kafka consumer then all the consumers can read from the same partition.

Answer (score 1):

> Can multiple Kafka consumers read from the same partition of same
>   topic by default?

Yes.

> By default, I mean since group.id is not mandatory I am wondering if I
>   spawn multiple kafka consumers without specifying any group.id and
>   give them the same topic and partition name will they be able to read
>   from the same partition?

Yes.

You can look at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs for
default values for consumer properties.