# Restrictions on number of consumer (belonging to same group) that can read from a partition simulltaneously?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Can more than one consumer belonging to the same consumer group read from a partition simultaneously.

I would guess no, so as to avoid processing of the same message more than once.

Yes if the consumers are from different groups, then yes multiple consumers can read from the same partition without any trouble. ([A SOF question is already posted on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135373/can-multiple-kafka-consumers-read-from-the-same-partition-of-same-topic-by-defau)).

But I am particularly asking about consumers from the same group reading from the same partition. Does kafka allow this?

Answer (score 2):

As you already pointed out Kafka doesn't allow it. In order to have something like that you can use the subscribe for a consumer and the assign for another specifying one or more partitions but the you could have the problems I described in the following article : https://paolopatierno.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/apache-kafka-consumer-groups-dont-use-them-in-the-wrong-way/

Comment: so explict `assign(...)` is the answer and the downfalls are clearly mentioned in your article. wonderful. tx